# What is cause of IE's "SCRIPT1010: Expected Identifier" error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, polyfills, angular9

We've just upgraded our Angular app from Angular 6 to Angular 9. The Angular 6 version runs fine in IE11 and Edge. The Angular 9 version of the app runs fine in Edge but errors out and will not load in IE11.

The error is:

```
"SCRIPT1010: Expected Identifier" in vendor.js
```

The error points to the first appearance of the "{" in the bundled vendor.js file at the expression below:

```
const { defaults } = __webpack_require__ ...
```

Since I have no control over the coding of the vendor.js file, I'm a bit at a loss as to how to prevent the error from occurring other than to enable all of the suggested polyfills for IE11 in the polyfills.ts file as below:

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js'; // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'hammerjs';
/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
import 'web-animations-js'; // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

// (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
// (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
// (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

/*
* in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
* with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
*/
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

if (typeof (window as any)['global'] === 'undefined') {
  (window as any)['global'] = window;
}

/**
 * Polyfill CustomEvent for IE
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Polyfill
 */
import 'custom-event-polyfill/polyfill';

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.

/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Update: Added tsconfig.json below:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noResolve": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: IE11 doesn't like the `const { defaults }` syntax in this context - and unfortunately Polyfills cannot correct for inadequacies in browsers' JavaScript parsers or syntax support: only missing library/DOM features (IE11 does support `const` and `let`, but not in every context).

Comment: What Webpack settings are you using? I suspect when you upgraded to Angular 9, one of your dependencies dropped support for IE in their Angular 9-compatible versions (Angular 9 promises IE11 support, but this doesn't extend to other dependencies).

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by @Dai you can check your dependencies. It may help to find the cause of the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem with IE11 and Angular 7.  The problem is "destructuring" in node_modules that are imported.  Spread causes similar issues.  

Typescript will process your code, but not the imported code, which is supposed to be pre-processed.

I think the trick will be to force processing of the imported code, I've done it in another (non-angular) project with Babel, but it's tricky.

Comment: Any solution to this issue..?